# Find all generators of $ (\mathbb{Z}_{27})^{\times} $

Tags: abstract-algebra

"Find all generators of $ (\mathbb{Z}_{27})^{\times} $"

My attempt is below.

Since $ (\mathbb{Z}_{n})^{\times} $ is a cyclic if and only if $ n = 1, 2, 4, p^n, 2p^n $, $ (\mathbb{Z}_{27})^{\times} $ is cyclic.

And the order of $ (\mathbb{Z}_{27})^{\times} $ is $ 3^3 - 3^2 = 18 $ by the Euler's phi function.

Thus $ (\mathbb{Z}_{27})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{18} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_9 $.

But I don't know how to get the 'all' generators.
('2' seems to be the 'one' generator, since 2 is of order 9 in $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$.)

Comment: Try not to get confused thinking about the multiplicative group of units of $\Bbb Z_{27}$ as the additive cyclic group $\Bbb Z_{18}$ :)

Comment: I'm not sure why the order of $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{18}$ tells you anything about the order of $2$ in $\mathbb Z_{27}^\times$. Yes, these two groups are isomoporphic, but the $2$ in one does not correspond to the $2$ in the other.

Comment: @rschwieb Are they different? Since they are 'finite abelian', I have thought that they can be isomorphic... I'm very confused... 'abstract algebra' is too 'abstract' :(

Comment: @user73309 No, what you wrote is fine! I just didn't want the fact that one was written multiplicatively and the other is written additively to confuse you. There isn't anything wrong with what you said.

Comment: 2 has multiplicative order 18 in $\Bbb Z_{27}$ as you noted below. When it is mapped into  $\Bbb Z_{18}$ however, it is mapped to one of the generators of $\Bbb Z_{18}$: $\{1,5,7,11,13,17\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If you are viewing the group as $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_9$, you are just looking for elements (pairs!) which have additive order 18. The orders of elements of the form $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ are all clear to you... but do you realize what the orders of elements of the form $(a,b)$ are?

If you really intend to chase these elements back to $(\Bbb Z_{27})^\times
$, you will have to explicitly write the map you have between this and $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_9$.

With lhf's hint, this is the way to go.

Comment: Finding the map between them could be the real problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user73309 Well, fortunately there are only finitely many ways to map :)

Comment: '2' in $\mathbb{Z}_{27}$ is of order 18 and it generates all elements which are relatively prime to 27. Then, could I say '2' is 'the' generator of the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}_{27}$? However it should have 'two' generators from my attempt....?????

Comment: @user73309 If you want to go about it this way, then you don't need to find elements in $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_9$. From the 18 elements which 2 generates multiplicatively, you can just take the ones which are powers of 2 which are coprime to 18.

Answer (score 4):

If you know one generator $g$ of a cyclic group of order $n$, then all others are of the form $g^k$ with $(k,n)=1$.